# image not retrieving from mysql using vb.net

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.IO

Imports System.Drawing

Public Class viewEmpDetail
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=admin; database=luludata;"
        con.Open()
        Dim sql As String
        Dim arrImage() As Byte
        'Try
        sql = "SELECT image FROM emp_detail WHERE emp_id = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        reader.Read()


        arrImage = reader.Item("image")
        dim mstream = New MemoryStream(arrImage)
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(mstream)             
         reader.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

I am trying to execute the code but parameter not valid error occur
i inserting image in database as blob file but while retrieving image getting eorro

Comment: What is the data type of `emp_id`? If it's numeric then you should not be using single quotes around the value. Single quotes in SQL denote text so you don't wrap them around numbers, just as double quotes denote `Strings` in VB so you don't wrap them around numbers. Of course, you should be using parameters to insert values in SQL code so there should not be such an issue. As your code is, a malicious user could delete everything in your database.

Comment: i remove single quotes from query but error is parameter is not valid at line picturebox1.image-image.fromstream(msstream)

Comment: data type of emp_id is int

Comment: It would appear that the data doesn't represent a valid `Image` object.

Comment: will u suggest me how to insert image into Mysql database